# Failed to register application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

If you are not able to run your application due to the following error:

Failed to register application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and run the following command:

netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Here you will see the list of used ports in a range e.g. from (start port) 10000 to (end port) 11000 etc. etc.

What you want to do is to go to the settings of your project and set a port that is not falling under any range of the listed ones in the CMD after running netsh interface command.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because the port on which the application wants to run is currently being used by another application.
Right click on the **sln** file and open the file in **notepad** and then edit **vmport** and then reload the project.

below link can help you :

[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another#:~:text=The%20main%20cause%20for%20this,being%20used%20by%20another%20process.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another#:%7E:text=The%20main%20cause%20for%20this,being%20used%20by%20another%20process.)